# How put the names of columns in Julia and put news files .csv in a second, third and so on column in Julia Language?

Tags: csv, julia

I would like to ask a naive question, but I haven't found it anywhere.
I am using the following code to build a .csv file

```
CSV.write ("try01.csv", DataFrame(X))
```

And I can see that you actually created a .csv file.
When I open the file with

```
df = DataFrame (CSV.File ("try01.csv"))
```

the correctly created table appears, but as my columns are waiting for "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4" and "x5".

I would like to rename them and I am not getting it.

Then I enter the site https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/
and the next meeting:

```
#Occupation
CSV.write (file, table; kwargs ...) => file
table |> CSV.write (file; kwargs ...) => file
```

But I cannot understand these parameters.

So, if possible, I have 3 rather naive questions:

1. How do I rename the columns?
2. If I want to make another file with an x6 column. How do I put this new file in the previous one that has 5 columns leaving the previous file with 6 columns?
3. How do I understand the documentation in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your code actually runs - things like `DataFrame (X)` are not valid Julia syntax, as you can't have whitespace between a function/constructor name and the arguments of the call.

That said, I believe you're just asking for how to change column names of a DataFrame, which you can do with the `rename!` function. Just do:

```
julia> using DataFrames

help?> rename!
search: rename! rename propertynames elementary_reaction_rate_params

  rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, vals::AbstractVector{Symbol};
          makeunique::Bool=false)
  rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, vals::AbstractVector{<:AbstractString};
          makeunique::Bool=false)
  rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, (from => to)::Pair...)
  rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, d::AbstractDict)
  rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, d::AbstractVector{<:Pair})
  rename!(f::Function, df::AbstractDataFrame)

  Rename columns of df in-place. Each name is changed at most once. Permutation of names is allowed.
```

And read the whole docstring.

Your second question seems to be how to append a column to an existing csv file - I don't think that's possible, the `append` keyword in `CSV.write` appends rows instead of columns. You could of course transpose your whole data and write columns as rows and vice versa.

The last question isn't exactly clear to me - are you asking how to understand

```
CSV.write(file, table; kwargs...) => file
table |> CSV.write(file; kwargs...) => file
```

If so, these are just two ways of calling `CSV.write`; the first `CSV.write(file, table; kwargs...)` just means call the function with `file` as the first argument (i.e. the path that you want your output file to appear in, including output file name) and `table` as the second argument, which is your DataFrame or other Tables.jl compatible table. Finally, `kwargs...` just means "any number of keyword arguments", which are passed as name/value pairs like `append = true`.

The second line `table |> CSV.write(file; kwargs...)` is essentially the same but using piping (see the docs here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Function-composition-and-piping for an explanation)